# Engravings in "Wandering the Immeasurable" sculpture outside the CERN globe?

Tags: specific-reference, history, large-hadron-collider

Does anyone have a PDF or a file that shows all of the engravings on the ["Wandering the Immeasurable" sculpture by Gayle Hermick](http://cds.cern.ch/search?ln=en&sc=1&p=WANDERING+THE+IMMEASURABLE&action_search=Search&op1=a&m1=a&p1=&f1=&rm=rrm&c=Articles+%26+Preprints&c=Books+%26+Proceedings&c=Presentations+%26+Talks&c=Periodicals+%26+Progress+Reports&c=Multimedia+%26+Outreach) outside of the CERN globe of science and initiative?

[image: A picture of the statue in question]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about finding a record of what's written on a sculpture. It's not about physics

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought this would be the best place to ask. Is there an off-topic but related to physics stack exchange to ask?

Comment: @Jimnosperm I dunno, I'm inclined to say it's on topic as it's looking for a very specific reference about something most people outside physics wouldn't even know existed (the LHC that is).

Comment: Plus, given the nature of physicists, it (and the decisions behind it) may actually be archived in a peer-reviewed journal somewhere.

Comment: There's some information and photos on the CERN document server (linked in question), but no detailed designs of the sculpture

Comment: The thing was laser printed, so what you want must probably does exist somewhere

Comment: This is my best: https://cds.cern.ch/record/1563838/files/Pe%CC%81re%CC%81grinations_image.jpg?subformat=

Comment: @tpg2114 no argument that it's looking for a very specific reference that only physicists would know about, but is it _about physics_? I don't think so, and therefore I consider it off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found [this computer generated picture](http://cds.cern.ch/record/1563838/files/Pe%CC%81re%CC%81grinations_image.jpg) of the engravings in an [article](http://cds.cern.ch/record/1563838?ln=en) in the CERN document server about the sculpture. You can't see everything, but it's quite high resolution and you can make out a lot of the writing if you zoom.

I'm not convinced that that computer generated image, however, matches the sculpture that was built in these [photos in the CERN document server](http://cds.cern.ch/record/1957174?ln=en). In any case, you might be able read a lot the writing from from a combination of the photos and the computer generated image.

Comment: If someone can easily incorporate the picture onto the answer, please do so!